# Stirling type formula for Sum on $\ln(n)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, asymptotics

Is there a similar formula like the Stirling one on the sum over $\ln(n)$ (take logarithms on its factorial representation):

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \ln(n) = N \ln(N)-N+\ln(N)/2+\ln(2\pi)/2+\mathcal{O}(\ln(N)/N)$$

but on the sum over its squares?

$$\sum_{n=1}^N (\ln(n))^2$$

I already advanced on getting good approximation on asymptotics integrating $\ln(n)^2$ and arrive to correct terms till $\mathcal{O}(N)$ order. But further advance is becoming hard for me in $\mathcal{O}(\ln(N))$ terms.

I am specially interested in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ term.

Comment: Have you tried the Euler-Maclaurin formula?

Comment: Maple says it's $$(\ln(N)^2 - 2 \ln(N)+2)N + \frac{\ln(N)^2}{2} -\frac{ \ln  \left( 2\,\pi \right)^{2}}{2}-\frac{{\pi}^{2}}{24}
+\frac{{\gamma}^{2}}{2}+\gamma \left( 1 \right)
+ \ldots $$

Comment: Sorry Robert, not sure what $$\gamma(1)$$ means

Comment: Thanks @LordSharktheUnknown to your suggestion I could arrive to the O(ln(N)^2) term. But still no clear idea on how to get constant term. I saw some proof of Stirling constant term but no general method to apply here. Any idea on that?

Comment: $\gamma \left( 1 \right) $ is [Stieltjes constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesConstants.html)

Comment: Any idea on how to get the value of the constant term? $$-\frac{ln(2\pi)^2}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{24}+\frac{\gamma_0^2}{2}+\gamma_1$$

Comment: I suspect something to do with derivatives of Riemann zeta function at origin, but no clear idea on how to relate to it, neither in how to calculate them. Any help on that too?

Comment: $$\sum _{n=1}^N \log ^2(n)=\sum _{n=1}^N \left(\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^2n^x}{\partial
   x^2}\right)=\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}\left(\sum _{n=1}^N
   n^x\right)=\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^2H_N^{(-x)}}{\partial x^2}=\underset{x\to
   0}{\text{lim}}(\text{HarmonicNumber}^{(0,2)}(N,-x))=\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{24}-\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(2 \pi
   )+\gamma _1-\zeta ^{(2,0)}(0,1+N)$$

Answer (score 2):

We can use the Euler-Maclaurin formula to obtain the asymptotic expansion
$$ f_N (a) \equiv \sum \limits_{n=1}^N n^a \sim \zeta(-a) + \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k^*}{a+1} {a+1 \choose k} N^{a+1-k} $$
for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1\}$ . Here $(B_k^*)_{k\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ are the Bernoulli numbers with $B_1^* = \frac{1}{2}$. We want to find an asymptotic expansion for 
$$f_N''(0) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^N \ln^2 (n) \, .$$ 
Obviously, the contribution of the terms with $k \geq 2$ vanishes as $N \to \infty$ . More precisely, their leading term is $\mathcal{O} (\ln^2 (N) /N)$ . Therefore we have
\begin{align}
\sum \limits_{n=1}^N \ln^2 (n) &\sim \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}a^2} \left[\zeta(-a) + \frac{N^{a+1}}{a+1} + \frac{1}{2} N^{a} \right] \Bigg\rvert_{a=0} + \mathcal{O} \left(\frac{\ln^2 (N)}{N}\right) \\
&\sim N \ln^2 (N) - 2 N \ln(N) + 2N + \frac{1}{2} \ln^2 (N) + \zeta''(0) + \mathcal{O} \left(\frac{\ln^2 (N)}{N}\right)
\end{align}
as $N \to \infty$ .

$\zeta''(0)$ can be found using the series expansions
\begin{align}
(2\pi)^s &= 1 + \ln(2 \pi) s + \frac{1}{2} \ln^2 (2 \pi) s^2 + \mathcal{O}(s^3) \, , \\
\sin \left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) &= \frac{\pi}{2} s - \frac{\pi^3}{48} s^3 + \mathcal{O}(s^5) \, , \\
\Gamma(1-s) &= 1 - \gamma s + \frac{6 \gamma^2 + \pi^2}{12} s^2 + \mathcal{O}(s^3) \, , \\
\zeta(1-s) &= - \frac{1}{s} + \gamma + \gamma_1 s + \mathcal{O}(s^2)
\end{align}
near $s = 0$ in the functional equation
\begin{align}
\zeta(s) &= \frac{1}{\pi} (2\pi)^s \sin \left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(1-s) \zeta(1-s)\\
&= - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \ln (2 \pi) s - \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{\pi^2}{24} + \frac{1}{2} \ln^2(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2} \gamma^2 - \gamma_1 \right] s^2 + \mathcal{O}(s^3)\, .
\end{align}
We obtain $\zeta(0) = -\frac{1}{2}$ , $\zeta'(0) = -\frac{1}{2} \ln(2 \pi)$ and
$$ \zeta''(0) = - \left[\frac{\pi^2}{24} + \frac{1}{2} \ln^2(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2} \gamma^2 - \gamma_1 \right] \, . $$

Comment: Could you please explain how do you get your first line? I repeat the Euler-Maclaurin summation, but I couldn't get your first line. I find this formula here: https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10#E2  but I couldn't derive it directly from the Euler-Maclaurin summation. Is there any reference to show the details?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered an exercise recently which gives an asymptotic formula
$$
\sum_1^N \log^2(n)= \left( n +\frac 12\right)\log^2(n) -2n \log(n) +2n + C + r_n \quad [r_n \to 0, C \text{a constant}].
$$
Hope this could help.

The derivation TBA...